# ReferenceError: Float64Array is not defined - Javascript with QML

Tags: javascript, qml, qt5, qtquick2, qt5.3

I am not using any browser. I am writing JS code along with QML.
Error is on this line:

```
var distanceBetweenPoints2DimArray = new Float64Array (0)
```

I need to store a float point value in an array in JS.

Comment: What do you mean by "This JS code works with QML"? On the next line you say there is an error..

Comment: @Mitch I meant that there is no browser involved. I am working with just QML and javascript.

Comment: Ok, it was confusing wording. :p

Comment: @Mitch I am not a native English speaker. Was just translating from Hindi to English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Specifications section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Float64Array#Specifications) of MDN's documentation for Float64Array says that it's an ECMAScript 6 feature, with ECMAScript 6 currently in draft status, so it's not implemented in Qt yet. A `git grep Float64Array` in qtdeclarative.git confirms this.

Searching through Qt's code review yields only one change from 2012 that was never merged:

https://codereview.qt-project.org/#/q/project:qt/qtdeclarative+message:typedarray,n,z

Searching through bug reports shows that it "should be implemented at some point":

https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-26265

Edit: I'm told that support for this is being worked on, with an initial estimate of being ready for Qt 5.5.